# How to refresh page in React native?

Tags: react-native

My dev env is

> "react": "17.0.1",
> "react-dom": "17.0.1",
> "react-hook-form": "^7.22.1",
> "react-native": "^0.64.3",

I'd like to refresh my page once I delete my comment.
Mostly in this case, I've used `navigation.goBack()` or `navigation.navigate("same page")` like below.

```
  const onDeleteClick = () => {
    deleteCommentMutation();
    navigation.navigate("Comments");
  };
```

But the problem is Comments page has Flatlist with data getting from the previous page.
On this page, I can't pass same data set ({route}) to Comments page.

So It refreshes my page but with no data, which means empty page.
I don't want that. I just refresh my page as deleting only one comment.

When I searched on Internet, people recommend `window.location.reload()`
But when I use it instead of navigation, it gives me error saying that:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.location.reload')

at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
```

Can't React native use window.location.reload()?
As far as I know, It doesn't need any installation or import.

How can I use window.location.reload()?
Otherwise, which way can I refresh my page?

---

Srimurugan Sri taught me that React can't use window ;) thanks.
So as he recommended I tried to use extraData.
as far as I understand, it watch any change on {data} part.
And if some change detected, automatically re-render flatlist.

So I made `useState` and added `extraData` as below.

```
 const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
  return (
    <Container>
      <CommentBox>
        <FlatList
          keyboardDismissMode={true}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={route?.params?.comments}
          keyExtractor={(comment) => "" + comment.id}
          renderItem={renderComment}
          extraData={selectedId}
        />
      </CommentBox>
    </Container>
  );
```

But it still doesn't refresh my page.
Can you teach me more?

**CommentRow page**

```
export default function CommentRow({
  id,
  user,
  payload,
  isMine,
  createdAt,
  updatedAt,
  commentNumber,
  photoId,
}) {
  const createdDate = new Date(+createdAt);
  const date = createdDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  const updateDeleteComment = (cache, result) => {
    const {
      data: {
        deleteComment: { ok, error },
      },
    } = result;
    if (ok) {
      cache.evict({ id: `Comment:${id}` });
      cache.modify({
        id: `Photo:${photoId}`,
        fields: {
          commentNumber(prev) {
            return prev - 1;
          },
        },
      });
    }
  };

  const [deleteCommentMutation] = useMutation(DELETE_COMMENT_MUTATION, {
    variables: {
      id,
    },
    update: updateDeleteComment,
  });
  const onDeleteClick = () => {
    deleteCommentMutation();
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <CommentContainer>
        <UserImage source={{ uri: user.avatar }} />
        <TextBox>
          <Header>
            <Username>{user.username}</Username>
            <CreatedTime>{date}</CreatedTime>
          </Header>
          <CommentText>{payload}</CommentText>
        </TextBox>
      </CommentContainer>
      {isMine ? (
        <WriteContainer>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <WriteComment>수정</WriteComment>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onDeleteClick}>
            <WriteComment>삭제</WriteComment>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </WriteContainer>
      ) : null}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such concept as "reload" in React Native. Once a Route is "mounted" it won't remount even if you navigate from and back to the component.

So I use the following idea to "reload" the component once I navigate to it from another one and when I want to reload the component on the refresh pull gesture

```
export class Props {
 refreshTimeStamp: string | undefined 
};
export class MainParamList {
  Main: Props
}

export default function ({
  route,
  navigation,
}: NativeStackScreenProps<MainParamList, 'Main'>) {
  const [data, setData] = setState<string>('')
  const refreshData = () => setData('result')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.refreshTimeStamp) {
      void refreshData();
    }
  }, [route.params]);


  return (      
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        }}
        refreshControl: {
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={false}
            onRefresh={() => {
              navigation.navigate('Main', { refreshTimeStamp: new 
  Date().toISOString() });
            }}
            style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
          />
        }
      >
      {data}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to refresh the data of Flatlist, you can Use the extraData property on your FlatList component instead of changing route.

we can't use `window.location.reload()` in React native.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the fact that React can't use it. But when I use extraData, it still doesn't work. I add this part on my post. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Since your source of data is from `route.params.comments`. Flatlist not will not refresh data Since you have extraData as SelectedID.

Please have your data in state and pass the same state to extraData.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
useEffect( () => {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState(route?.params?.comments); 
  // update the comments after deleting using setComments() syntax;
},[])    
//Both data & extraData is comments
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

  return (
    <Container>
      <CommentBox>
        <FlatList
          keyboardDismissMode={true}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={comments} 
          keyExtractor={(comment) => "" + comment.id}
          renderItem={renderComment}
          extraData={comments}
        />
      </CommentBox>
    </Container>
  );
  // You cannot use window.location.reload() in react native, but you can use in Web development
```

Comment: thanks a lot. const [comments, setComments] exists in useEffect function so I can't use it outside. So I have it as this picture. => https://ifh.cc/v-5B9yAL

Comment: please help me just one more thing. thank you in advance for your help. problem is I render the data with new screen named `CommentRow`. So I need to pass `setComments` to new screen because the process to delete comment happens on 'CommentRow' Screen. So I need to change setComments state on that screen after deleting the comment. but I don't how.. I pass the data like ` <CommentRow {...passedComments} />` as an object. So I can't add setComments data with it.

Comment: Is it working?, If not please share your commentRow component.

Comment: it's not working. I add commentRow component on my first post :)

Comment: It seems you are deleting your comments using some third party client, So you need to fetch your updated comments from them.

Comment: yes right. but I don't know how to fetch data in this case T_T can you help me in this part?

Comment: create a function in Comments component to fetch and set the updated comments. Pass the function as call back to the commentsRow. Call the callback function whenerever you are deleting the comments. So your call back will fetch the latest comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241306/discussion-between-srimurugan-sri-and-hyejung).

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure why you r doing this way ( react is reactive framework so use it ) but you can pass props to your SCREEN

```js
navigation.navigate('Comments', {setData: setData, data: data});
```

data => comments is just name

then inside your "Comments" ( CommentsScreeen ), just call "setData" from route params like

```js
interface CommentsScreenRouteProps {
    key: string,
    name: string,
    params: {
        data,
        setData: React.Dispatch<any>,
    },
    path: string,
}
...
const route = useRoute<CommentsScreenRouteProps>();
...

route.params.setData(route.params.data.filter(() => true))
```

there are maybe only 2 problems with my example, but 1st can be fixed, 2nd ignored

1. st both screens get rerender ( with is performance problem )

- can be fixed with REACT NATIVE FREEZE ( added in rect 17 )
- there is small helper package https://github.com/software-mansion/react-freeze

2. you get warrning cuz u sending React.Dispatch, with is not passible to serialize but its not WRONG its just warrning in console ...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to force a re-render on a screen, one way that you can do so is to use the [useFocusEffect hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/). It will fire each time that the screen gains focus.

In the OP's case, it sounds like the ask is to re-render the current screen while the user is still on it. In this case, you could update an item of state to force a re-render. The state item itself doesn't have to be displayed anywhere on the screen:

```
const [dummyState, setDummyState] = useState(0);

// Connect this function to the onPress prop of a Button as an example.
// For the OP's case, you could add it into the code that deletes the comment, 
// directly after the comment is deleted.
function btnHandler() {
    // This will force a re-render.
    setDummyState(Date.now());
}
```

As others have noted, forcing a re-render is generally not recommended, but if you do have a special case where you really want to re-render, you can use one of these techniques to get the job done.